# SQL statement not executing properly from variable in SQL server

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to create temp table through variable like following but I am not getting error

```
Declare @cSQL varchar(Max) = 'Select top 10 * into #TempTab from Customer'

EXEC (@cSQL)

select * from  #TempTab
```

I am getting following error

> (10 row(s) affected)
>   Msg 208, Level 16, State 0, Line 4
>   Invalid object name '#CurTemp'.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2920836/local-and-global-temporary-tables-in-sql-server

Comment: Possible duplicate of [T-SQL Dynamic SQL and Temp Tables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2917728/t-sql-dynamic-sql-and-temp-tables)

Answer (score 0):

Temp table is for that scope alone not for outside scope. You might require to create global temp table as below:

```
Declare @cSQL varchar(Max) = 'Select top 10 * into ##TempTab from Customer'

EXEC (@cSQL)

select * from ##TempTab
```

Though it is not advisable