# Temp table value in where clause of Dynamic SQL

Tags: sql-server, dynamic-sql, temp-tables

Need to know whether below Syntax is correct while using a value from temp table in where clause of dynamic SQL

```
DECLARE @sqlQ nvarchar(1000);

if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Tem') is not null BEGIN DROP tABLE #Tem END
create table #Tem
(order nvarchar(10))

insert into #Tem
Select orderID from customerdetails where  OrderID >100


  SET @sqlQ = N'UPDATE FINALTable SET Highvalcusomer=1 where 
   orderno=#Tem.order'
      EXEC @sqlQ
```

Comment: No, that's not right. What are you actually trying to achieve here?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [T-SQL Dynamic SQL and Temp Tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2917728/t-sql-dynamic-sql-and-temp-tables)

Comment: I need to compare the value from temp table and  the table which I am going to update

Comment: Also need to know the above given syntax of dynamic query is correct or not since I am using #Tem.order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do it in one go

```
   UPDATE 
    FINALTable 
   SET 
    Highvalcusomer=1 
   where 
     orderno IN (Select orderID from customerdetails where  OrderID >100)
```

Or if you really want to use dynamic SQL

```
SET @sqlQ = N'UPDATE FINALTable SET Highvalcusomer=1 where 
            orderno IN (Select orderID from #Tem)'
EXEC (@sqlQ )
```

`#Tem` will be in scope for the dynamic SQL

Comment: Is it possible to use without 'orderno IN' and just map as above in the question?

Comment: The name N'UPDATE FINALTable SET Highvalcusomer=1 where 
   orderno IN (Select orderID from #Tem)'   is not a valid identifier          got this error