# Select * into #Temp not working in dynamic SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

When I create a temporary table and insert data into that temporary table through dynamic SQL its work fine. But when I use `select * into  #TempTable1 from YourTable` in dynamic SQL it throw error. I am unable to understand the cause of this error.

**Table:**

```
create table YourTable(Id int identity(1,1),Col1 varchar(100));

insert into YourTable(Col1)
values('Stack'),('Over'),('Flow')
```

**Working Code:-**

```
Declare @SqlStr varchar(max)

create table #TempTable(Id int identity(1,1),Col1 varchar(100))
set @SqlStr='Insert into #TempTable(Col1) select Col1 from YourTable'
exec(@SqlStr)
select * from  #TempTable
```

**Not Working Code:**

```
Declare @SqlStr varchar(max)
set @SqlStr='select * into  #TempTable1 from YourTable'
exec(@SqlStr)
select * from  #TempTable1
```

**Error:**

> Msg 208 Level 16 State 0 Line 4
>   Invalid object name '#TempTable1'.

For Reference data is [here.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d2a40c2f55b870550d2e9afd7ba94516)

Comment: The dynamic SQL is run under a different context, it doesn't exist once you return from the `exec` call.

Comment: how `Insert into #TempTable(Col1) select Col1 from YourTable` run if dynamic sql run under a different context while  a local temprory table exist  in other context?

Comment: `exec(@SqlStr)` creates a new context in which `#TempTable1` is created. As you have shown it `select * from  #TempTable1` comes after `exec(@SqlStr)` and is therefore in a higher context in which `#TempTable1` does not exist.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [T-SQL Dynamic SQL and Temp Tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2917728/t-sql-dynamic-sql-and-temp-tables)

Comment: Thanks @DaleK this link is helpful. Update this comment in answer section so i'll be able to mark correct answer for this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cause of this error is that a temp table is session bound and your dynamic SQL runs in a separate session.

Use a global temp table (prefix: ##) and make this one unique by naming (i.e. add a guid to the name). This way the dynamic SQL can see it.

Different types temporary tables: http://www.sqlines.com/articles/sql-server/local_and_global_temporary_tables

Comment: If dynamic SQL run in other session then how `Insert into #TempTable(Col1) select Col1 from YourTable` run which is exist in other session.

Comment: Please try again - i can not answer to a sentence that I do not understand.

Comment: In my question there is a working code. In which i create a temporary table and insert values using dynamic sql. If dynamic sql runs in separate session then how it insert values in temporary table which was created in other session.