# What am I missing to execute stored procedure in OpenQuery

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, openquery

I am trying to use OpenQuery to insert data into a temporary table. OpenQuery suppose to execute a stored procedure that outputs hundreds of rows.

In order to not to defining `Create Table #temp1`, I am trying to execute OpenQuery and inserting the result into `#temp1` table using into statement in `Select` query. I would like to know what is causing it not to execute?

1. It seems like it may quotes issue which is not placed correctly. How can I get help related to this?
2. My server contains multiple databases (instances). How do I need to define it here?

I am providing an example here of my query here

```
DECLARE @startDate DATETIME = CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE());
DECLARE @endDate DATETIME = CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()+1);

DECLARE @stDate NVARCHAR(MAX) = CHAR(39) + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(255), @startDate, 23)+ CHAR(39) + ',';
DECLARE @enDate NVARCHAR(MAX) = CHAR(39) + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(255), @endDate, 23) + CHAR(39);
DECLARE @execCommand NVARCHAR(MAX) = CHAR(39) + 'EXEC dbo.getRecordsByOrderDate ' ;
DECLARE @concatCommand NVARCHAR(MAX) = @execCommand + @stDate + @enDate + CHAR(39);

DECLARE @opQuery Nvarchar(MAX) = 'Select * Into #Temp1 from Openquery(LOCALSERVER, '+ @concateCommand +') oq'

EXEC (@opQuery);
```

**Error Message:**

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 20 Incorrect syntax near '2020'.

If I try to execute in below format

```
Select * Into #Temp1 from Openquery(LOCALSERVER, 'EXEC dbo.getRecordsByOrderDate ''2020-12-11'',''''2020-12-12''''') oq
```

> Msg 11529, Level 16, State 1, Procedure
> sys.sp_describe_first_result_set, Line 1 [Batch Start Line 31] The
> metadata could not be determined because every code path results in an
> error; see previous errors for some of these.

> Msg 2812, Level 16,
> State 62, Procedure sys.sp_describe_first_result_set, Line 1 [Batch
> Start Line 31] Could not find stored procedure
> 'dbo.getRecordsByOrderDate'.

Comment: this may be your issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2917728/t-sql-dynamic-sql-and-temp-tables

Comment: Why do you say it doesn't execute?

Comment: @Larnu Please check my error message

Comment: @Jeremy: In-Order to not to define `CREATE TABLE ` I have used `INTO` statement.

Comment: *"Incorrect syntax near '2020'."* `2020` isn't in your code, nor does it have 20 lines; that error isn't in the SQL above, it's in something *else*. It's the Procedure that's erroring not the code above...

Comment: there will be a scoping issue. if you define a temp table inside dynamically executed SQL, then the outer stored procedure will not be able to reference the table.

Comment: ... I see the problem, it's the injection of your parameters... If you `PRINT` the value of `@concatCommand` you'll see your parameters aren't properly quoted, as they are a literal string **inside** a literal string. The quotes are escaping the value outer string; there needs to be 2 single quotes, not one.

Comment: @Larnu based on you above comment. "2020" comes from a variable `@startDate` and `@endDate` decalred on first line. Now line 20, my SSMS tab have multiple lines of SQL Query out ot this I am sharing only that is needed to post here. So line varies

Comment: @Larnu With all due respect Sir, I removed that so that I am not hurting anyone.

Comment: @Larnu Many apologies I wasn't meant in that sense.

Comment: as always, I have topost the bible on dynamic SQL. http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html

Answer (score 2):

The problem is your lack of escapting the quotes on your injected parameters. The simplest way to debug dynamic code is to `PRINT`/`SELECT` it. If you do that you'll quickly see the problem:

```sql
DECLARE @startDate DATETIME = CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE());
DECLARE @endDate DATETIME = CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()+1);

DECLARE @stDate NVARCHAR(MAX) = CHAR(39) + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(255), @startDate, 23)+ CHAR(39) + ',';
DECLARE @enDate NVARCHAR(MAX) = CHAR(39) + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(255), @endDate, 23) + CHAR(39);
DECLARE @execCommand NVARCHAR(MAX) = CHAR(39) + 'EXEC dbo.getRecordsByOrderDate ' ;
DECLARE @concatCommand NVARCHAR(MAX) = @execCommand + @stDate + @enDate + CHAR(39);

DECLARE @opQuery Nvarchar(MAX) = 'Select * Into #Temp1 from Openquery(LOCALSERVER, '+ @concatCommand +') oq'

PRINT @opQuery;
```

Which returns...

```sql
Select *
Into #Temp1
from Openquery(LOCALSERVER, 'EXEC dbo.getRecordsByOrderDate '2020-12-11','2020-12-12'') oq
```

Voila your first parameter escapes the second parameter, and thus the error. *(I Have added additional lines, as SO's choice of "prettifier" thinks `#` is a comment character in SQL, and I want the escaping to be highlighted in the colouring.)*

When using single quotes inside a literal string, you need to escape them by "doubly them up" (`''`). Thus the final statement needs to me the below:

```sql
Select *
Into #Temp1
from Openquery(LOCALSERVER, 'EXEC dbo.getRecordsByOrderDate ''20201211'',''20201212''') oq
```

*(Additional lines added for presentation again.)*

So you need to fix the definitions of your 2 injected values:

```sql
DECLARE @stDate NVARCHAR(8) = CHAR(39) + CHAR(39) + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(8), @startDate, 112)+ CHAR(39) + CHAR(39) + ',';
DECLARE @enDate NVARCHAR(8) = CHAR(39) + CHAR(39) + CONVERT(NVARCHAR(8), @endDate, 112) + CHAR(39) + CHAR(39);
```

Note I change the data types and styles too. The style as `yyyy-MM-dd` isn't unambiguous in SQL Server, and the data types, as you don't need 2 billion characters for a date.

---

Note, however, that after executing this you still won't be able to access `#Temp1`. A temporary table only persists for the scope it was created in, and that scope is the dynamic SQL's. You'll need to use a permanent table inside the dynamic statement, or `CREATE` a temporary table outside of the dynamic statement to use it outside of it.

Comment: Good explaination. Appreciate that.