# Dynamic Pivot Sql Query display all from one table

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot, dynamic-pivot

TABLE-A:-

| Custno | Name | Route | Phone |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | C1 | 1 | 12345 |
| 2 | C2 | 1 | 23456 |
| 3 | C3 | 2 | 34567 |
| 4 | C4 | 1 | 45678 |
| 5 | C5 | 1 | 56789 |

TABLE-B:-

| ODate | Custno | Route | ProductId | qty |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-04-22 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 100 |
| 2021-04-22 | 1 | 1 | 3 | 200 |
| 2021-04-22 | 2 | 1 | 1 | 120 |

Table-C

| ProductId | BrandName |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Brand-1 |
| 2 | Brand-2 |
| 3 | Brand-3 |

EXPECTED RESULT

| Phone | CustNo | Name | Brand-1 | Brand-2 | Brand-3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | 1 | C1 | 100 |  | 200 |
| 23456 | 2 | C2 | 120 |  |  |
| 45678 | 4 | C4 |  |  |  |
| 56789 | 5 | C5 |  |  |  |

What I tried Using Dynamic Pivot

```
DECLARE @query  AS VARCHAR(MAX)
, @cols_ AS  vARCHAR(MAX)

--Making the column list dynamically 
select @cols_ = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(brandname) from [Table-C] order by productid FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') ,1,1,'')              


print @cols_
--preparing PIVOT query dynamically. 

SET @query  = ' SELECT
       pivoted.* 
      into #Temp_data
      FROM 
      (
    select a.phone,a.custno,a.[name],d.BrandName,c.qty from [Table-A] a inner join [Table-B] c on a.custno = c.custno inner join [Table-C] d on c.productid = d.Productid and a.Route='1' and c.odate='2021-04-22'

      ) AS [p]
      PIVOT
      (
         MIN([P].[qty]) 
         FOR  [P].[BrandName]  IN (' + @cols_ + ')
      ) AS pivoted

      order by custno;

      select *        
       from #Temp_data [B]
      -- GROUP BY [B].[ODate]  

      drop table #Temp_data
   ';
  EXEC (@query)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [T-SQL Dynamic SQL and Temp Tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2917728/t-sql-dynamic-sql-and-temp-tables)

Comment: No, it is different from this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can reconstruct the query

```sql
SELECT *  
  FROM
  (
     SELECT A.[Phone], A.[CustNo], A.[Name], C.[BrandName], B.[qty]
       FROM [Table-A] AS A 
       LEFT JOIN [Table-B] AS B
         ON A.[CustNo] = B.[CustNo] 
        AND B.[odate] = '2021-04-22'
       LEFT JOIN [Table-C] AS C on C.productid = B.Productid  
      WHERE A.[Route] = 1  
      ) t
    PIVOT 
    (
     MIN([qty]) FOR [BrandName] IN ([Brand-1],[Brand-2],[Brand-3])
    ) AS piv
```

which contains `LEFT JOIN` rather than `INNER JOIN`, and `STRING_AGG()` function in order to generate the pivoted columns dynamically as in the following code block

```
DECLARE @cols  AS NVARCHAR(MAX),  @query AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @cols = ( SELECT STRING_AGG(QUOTENAME([BrandName]),',') 
                FROM (SELECT DISTINCT [BrandName] 
                        FROM [Table-C] ) C );

SET @query = 
  N'SELECT *  
      FROM
      (
         SELECT A.[Phone], A.[CustNo], A.[Name], C.[BrandName], B.[qty]
           FROM [Table-A] AS A 
           LEFT JOIN [Table-B] AS B
             ON A.[CustNo] = B.[CustNo] 
            AND B.[odate] = ''2021-04-22''
           LEFT JOIN [Table-C] AS C on C.productid = B.Productid  
          WHERE A.[Route] = 1  
          ) t
        PIVOT 
        (
         MIN([qty]) FOR [BrandName] IN (' + @cols + N')
        ) AS piv'

EXEC sp_executesql @query;
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d6cbfaec74be59a9a4938462d05acab5)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

for those of us who SQL server < 2017 you can replace the @cols with the following

```
    set @cols = (
select distinct stuff((
        select ',' + t1.[BrandName]
        from (select distinct [BrandName] from [Table-C]) t1
        order by t1.[BrandName]
        FOR XML PATH('')), 1, LEN(','), '') AS Brands
    )
```